# Delete directories with name longer than x

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need to delete directories on Linux shell which names are longer than 4 characters.
But don't count length of sub-directories.

For example:

```
/12345/..    <= Should be deleted
/123456/..   <= Should be deleted
/1234/12345  <= Should NOT be deleted
/1234/123456 <= Should NOT be deleted
```

**UPDATE:**
Got it:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -type d -regex '.*[^/]{4}' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: You should look into the `find` utility.

Comment: I did..
But that delete ALL dirs find -regextype posix-egrep -type d -regex '.*[^/]{4}' -delete

Comment: Well, obviously your regexp does not conform to what you try to achieve. What you want is the first word between slashes to be longer than your limit. Maybe smth in the spirit of `^/[^/]{4+}/` ?

Comment: And by the way, what language you plan to use to achieve the result? Is it shell, C, smth else? The question would benefit from specifying that.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all directories with 5 or more characters in `bash`, you could do :

```
rm -rf ?????*/
```

The expression is **not** a regular expression, but a glob pattern that uses a set of wildecard characters to specify a filename or path.

Basically, if you want to keep your directories with 4 characters or less, you want to remove everything with 5 or more, hence the 5 `?` and single `*`. The `/` indicates the directory.

> **`man bash`**
>
> `*` :: Matches  any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is enabled, and `*` is used in a pathname
>   expansion context, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match only directories and
>   subdirectories.
>
> `?` :: Matches any single character.

```
$ find .
.
$ mkdir -p {1,12,123,1234,12345,123456}/{123,12345}
$ touch foobar
$ rm -rf ?????*/
$ find .
.
./123
./123/12345   <= subdirectory with 5 or more not deleted
./123/123
./foobar      <= the file is still here
./1234
./1234/12345
./1234/123
./12
./12/123
./12/12345
./1
./1/12345
./1/123
```

Answer (score 1):

For legibility, pipe to `grep` then to `xargs`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep '.....' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: On Linux, you usually have gnu-find, which has a -delete switch. And it has a name param too: -name '.....*' - no need for grep and xargs. But not even for find, if you happen to use -maxdepth 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '?????*' -delete
```

It works for deeper nested dirs too, if you don't want to restrict yourself to -maxdepth 1.

Else

```
rm -rf ?????*/
```

is of course more brief and elegant. My first idea, rmdir, of course only works with empty dirs. I didn't think about that.

Use

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '?????*' -ls
```

before issuing the delete option, since it is irreversible. And backup often, if using find ... -delete on a regular basis. :)

Comment: I though `rmdir` only works if the directory is empty. What would work is `rmdir -p ?????*/**/` and ignore the first warnings. However, it fails again from the moment a single file is in any of the directories.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't think of that - I rarely delete directories in the shell. Will correct my post immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-regextype` for `find`.

```
$ pdirpath="/path/to/search"
$ find "$pdirpath" -type d -regextype posix-extended \
   -regex "$pdirpath/[a-z0-9]{5,}" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Above will remove directories that are,

```
/path/to/search/fooba
/path/to/search/12345
/path/to/search/foobar
```

*NOT*

```
/path/to/search/foobar/12345
/path/to/search/1234
```